# How to keep and display the current username in input form?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I started using Ion Auth and want to make a custom Login form. I'd like know how to keep and display the current username in this input form after user has clicked on 'Submit' button and validation message is wrong? I saw this method used a lot on sites but I can't find any examples that shows how to do it.

Ex: In situation that he doesn't have a password correct...

Noticed I test the example by default, when user has enter an incorrect password, error msg pops up and when clicked on Submit, his current username or email is blank, doesn't store in input form.

UPDATED here's my current code:

Controller

```
    public function login() {

    // Validated login form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    // Get user input form
    $username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
    $password = $this->input->post('password', TRUE);

    // If it can't log in
    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== true) {
        $data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'); 

        $data['username'] = array(  'name'      => 'username', 
                                    'type'      => 'text',
                                    'value'     => set_value('username') ); 

        $data['password'] = array(  'name'  => 'password',
                                    'type'  => 'password' );

        $data['submit'] = array (        'type' => 'submit',
                                    'value' => 'Login' );   

        // Display login page
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    } else {
        // User success login
        if ($this->ion_auth->login($username, $password)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect($this->config->item('base_url'), 'refresh');               
        } else {
            // Display error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->set_error('Invalid username or password.'));

            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<div id='login_form'>
<?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>
    <p><?php echo form_input($username);?></p>
    <p><?php echo form_password($password);?></p>

    <div id="message"><?php echo $message;?></div>
    <p id="submit"><?php echo form_submit($submit);?></p>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: don't use `$this->form_validation->set_value('username')` just use `set_value('username')`

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not working. When I click on Submit, it doesn't show up the current username in input form. I don't know what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You would use `set_value()` to keep the value if `form_validation` is false, CodeIgniter will retain the values.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" 
       name="quantity" 
       value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0'); ?>" 
       size="50" />
```

**Reference:** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: It doesn't work, it still giving me the default which is 'Username' I use form_input($username) instead and have defined an associative array... Any ideas?

Comment: it works.. you're not doing it right: `set_value('name of element')` if you have an `ID` defined in you associative array, it is not the same, you need a name. verify that they match and it will work, see the CI reference I have included and review your code.

Comment: Ok, I removed ID defined but keep Name defined which is 'username'. It still not working. That's weird!